# Remove randomly generated sprites with Mouse.Event

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a game for my class where different chemical elements are generated as sprites at the top of the screen and then fall down.  Different types are made and I want students to mouse over specific types depending on where they are in the game.
  My question is how to write the function to remove them when they are correctly selected?  I've tried a lot of different ways but am having a lot of trouble.  An example of the code that I wrote to make each element is below and then I have a separate function to move down all of the sprites created.

```
var spriteArray:Array = new Array();
var halogenArray:Array = new Array("F", "Cl", "Br", "I");
var rndnum:Number = Math.random();              
//Halogens
if (rndnum < 0.05)
{
var halo:Sprite = new Sprite();  
halo.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 1);
halo.graphics.drawCircle(7.5, 7.5, 15);
halo.graphics.endFill();
halo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, removeElement);
halo.x = Math.random()*500 + 50;
halo.y = -18;
var textField = new TextField();
textField.text = halogenArray[int(Math.random()*4)];
textField.width = 30; 
textField.height = 30;
textField.x = (15 - textField.textWidth)/2; // center it horizontally
textField.y = (15 - textField.textHeight)/2; // center it vertically
halo.addChild(textField);
spriteArray.push(halo);
addChild(halo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
//give your textfields a name, it isn't totally necessary as we can do getChildAt(0)
//but it's more readable, and if you decide to add more children before you
//add the text field, then this will still work

var textField = new TextField();
textField.text = halogenArray[int(Math.random()*4)];
textField.width = 30; 
...
textField.name = "haloTx"; //for tracking later

//assuming you have some variable set to the correct answer
var correctAnswer:String = "F";

function removeElement( e:MouseEvent ):void {
    var element:TextField = ( e.target as Sprite ).getChildByName( "haloTx" );

    //if we have the correct element, remove from parent and list
    if ( element && element.text == correctAnswer ) {
        var index:int = spriteArray.indexOf( e.target as Sprite );
        removeChild( spriteArray.splice( index, 1 )[0] );
    }
}
```

Although @VBCPP is right, doing that in a separate class is definitely the best way organizationally. Which might look something like:

```
class ElementSprite extends Sprite {
    public var textField:TextField;

    //pass shapeArgs as string, so say a circle at x=7.5, y=7.5, and radius=15 -- shapeArgs = "7.5, 7.5, 15"
    public function ElementSprite( element:String, drawShape:String="Circle", shapeArgs:String="7.5, 7.5, 15", fillColor:uint=0x00FF00 ) {
        //set textfield properties etc. or textFormat
        textField = new TextField();
        textField.text = element;
        addChild( textField );

        //if you passed some arguments to draw our shape
        if ( shapeArgs != "" ) {
            graphics.beginFill( fillColor );
            graphics[ "draw" + drawShape ].apply( this, shapeArgs.split( "," ) );
        }
    }

    public function get currentElement():String { return textField.text }
}
```

Then you would use it like so in your if statement `if (rndnum < 0.05)`:

```
var elementSprite:ElementSprite = new ElementSprite( "A" );
//elementSprite.x = set your x;
//elementSprite.y = set your y;
addChild(elementSprite);
```

That would be replacing all your current code in that if statement. This is all a working example, if you have an questions feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

At what point are you struggling?

I am assuming it is in determining the types of the halogens.
In your remove function I assume you have the desired type already figured out, you would then compare it to
    element.getChildAt(0).text
and you would get the element by either looping across every element in the spriteArray, or using the mouseEvent's target

My suggestion is to use a halogen Class to contain the grapics & textfield, and a vector to hold the objects. It would then be easier to get the type rather than searching the anonymous children of the sprite.